# Texture to Painted Vertex Algorithm

Tags: textures, algorithm, vertex-arrays

I want to generate some game textures into coloured vertex arrays.

Is there a known algorithm  to transform texture/bitmap data into an optimised vertex array. Much like how the [Homeworld skyboxes](http://simonschreibt.de/gat/homeworld-2-backgrounds/) were made.

*EDIT:*
Don't need the dome part, would like todo these flat.

Comment: Thanks for the blog link about homeworld skyboxes! Very interesting technique. Following.

Comment: Does your 3D version need to form a sphere, like in the Homeworld example, or are you looking for a flat rectangular shape, or some other topology?  Can you give an example of the textures you'll be using?

Comment: @DMGregory I should have mentioned, currently these will be flat. Although later I might wish to add some depth its not currently planned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I need is a `vertex collapse` algorithm that is typically used with reducing excess polycount.

http://pomax.nihongoresources.com/downloads/PolygonReduction.pdf

but create a different cost formula.